# Query to locate stored procedures by Prefix

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I was in a database this morning that has just short of 10k non system stored procedures. I am looking for a group of about 20 of them by name. When I attempt to select the node to view them it throws an error. I guess from attempting to show that many stored procedures.

I am having a hard time finding the correct syntax on Google. 
So I figured I would just ask and give it a good title so others can find it in the future.

So here is the code I have so far

```
SELECT ROUTINE_NAME
FROM SYS.OBJECTS
WHERE ROUTINE_NAME LIKE '%PER_%' 
AND ROUTINE_TYPE= 'PROCEDURE'
ORDER BY ROUTINE_NAME ASC
```

Comment: Why do you have a leading wildcard if looking for stored procedures specifically prefixed "PER"? Also you might want to check out (free) Redgate SQL Search.

Comment: Because i did not know any better, but I do now :), a lot of example online have leading and trailing wildcards. I though it was part of the LIKE syntax ..

Comment: Yeah http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx Says it matches anywhere the word is. It explains more when I read down. But thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: **FREE** [Red-Gate SQL Search](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-search)

Comment: Link is not working for me for some reason, will try again later

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that you are querying the wrong system view. That seems to be the view `Information_Schema.Routines`:

```
SELECT ROUTINE_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES
WHERE ROUTINE_TYPE = 'PROCEDURE'
AND ROUTINE_NAME LIKE 'PER_%'
ORDER BY ROUTINE_NAME ASC
```